# Why does MySQL truncate float 6.099999904632568 into 6.1

Tags: mysql, activerecord, floating-point

I understand that float is an approximation which depends on the precision that you want. However, I am confused as to why it converts `6.099999904632568` into `6.1`. Why does it need to round it instead of stopping at its maximum precision (i.e. `6.09999990`)

Is there anyway that I can force a number to be stored at its maximum precision without being rounded up?

## Table info

`` CREATE TABLE `urls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gcloud_magnitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1193 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ``

## Code to reproduce

`mysql> INSERT INTO urls (url_md5, gcloud_magnitude, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('noop', 6.099999904632568, '2018-09-16 14:57:49', '2018-09-16 14:57:49');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`

`mysql> SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url_md5 = 'noop'\G;
              id: 1193
         url_md5: noop
gcloud_magnitude: 6.1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

## Ruby interpreter parsing as float

`irb(main):004:0> Url.find_by(url_md5: 'noop').gcloud_magnitude.to_f
=> 6.1`

Comment: Only fixed point representation is able to do so. All floating point representation will look like some kind of rounding. You should think in bits instead of decimal digits: the actual number is the sum of `b*2^i` series instead of `d*10^i`. The rest depends on the actual bit representation used. Take a look here: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: I do not understand that link. I went there and entered `6.099999904632568`. According to the site, the value actually stored becomes `6.099999904632568359375`. The binary is `01000000110000110011001100110011`. Based on that, I am still confused as to why when I insert a record with a value of `6.099999904632568`, the output is `6.1`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @okysabeni: ISTM that the **output** routines do the rounding. The value is indeed stored as you found out on the web site. FWIW, as double, exactly the same value is stored (with a lot of trailing zero bits).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis. It is saving it as `6.1` in the database.

Comment: @oysabeni: as text? Otherwise, it is saving it as a 4 byte float with the indicated value.

Comment: @okysabeni: Also note that a 4 byte float can never store 6.1 as such. The closest value to 6.1 it can store *is exactly*  6.099999904632568359375, or as 32 bit hex value: 40C33333.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you see, `6.1`, is probably a so called [roundtrip](https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-shortest-decimal-string-that-round-trips-examples/) output. That is *the shortest output that, when parsed, will get back the same value as it was*. Not all languages output floats or doubles as roundtrip, but some do, unless explicitly told otherwise. I guess Ruby is one of them.

The value `6.1`, when parsed as float, gets the exact value `6.099999904632568359375`, but the value `6.099999904632568`, when parsed, gets the exact same value. `6.1` is the shortest output that can be generated for that particular float and when read back (parsed again), it will generate the same float.

Comment: Hey Rudy, I updated my question with more information. Specifically, I posted the table info as specified by `SequelPro` app. I then inserted a record with a `glcoud_manitude` value of `6.099999904632568`. I then read back that value and saw that the return value for `gcloud_magnitude` is `6.1` and I try to parse it as float and it still is `6.1`. Perhaps I do not understand your point on `roundtrip output`. When you say, it gets parsed back and gets the exact same value, what does that mean?

Comment: Something interesting happened. When I updated my schema to a decimal type with precision 64 and scale 30, all the correct values appear. So, MySQL does save it in some form but unable to represent it correctly and there is no way to fetch it back with the original value unless you provide enough precision.

Comment: @okysabene: You should perhaps get acquanited with the peculiarities of floating point types like float or double. Here is the tag description for that subject: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info . You can find a lot of info there.

Comment: FWIW, interesting article about the topic: https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Answer (score 1):

The `FLOAT` data type in MySQL doesn't have enough precision to store the value you gave. The `DOUBLE` data type can do it.

Example:

```
mysql> create table f ( f float, d double);

mysql> insert into f values (6.099999904632568, 6.099999904632568);

mysql> select * from f;
+------+-------------------+
| f    | d                 |
+------+-------------------+
|  6.1 | 6.099999904632568 |
+------+-------------------+
```

`FLOAT` rounds the value to the precision it can store. In fact, the rounding occurs even with values with less precision that the value you used.

```
mysql> select * from f;
+---------+-------------------+
| f       | d                 |
+---------+-------------------+
|     6.1 | 6.099999904632568 |
|     6.1 |         6.0999999 |
|     6.1 |          6.099999 |
| 6.09999 |           6.09999 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

There just aren't enough bits in a 32-bit `FLOAT` to store unlimited precision. So it has to round off the value.

You'll find there's a limit to the precision of a `DOUBLE` as well. It stores values in a 64-bit format.

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks for the answer. I learned a lot. Suppose I am OK with losing some precision but I want it to store it in the highest precision it can for the value that I provide. In other words, using your example, if I enter `6.099999`, it rounds it to `6.09999` (i.e. 4 9s after the decimal instead of 5). Does MySQL not know how to do that? I feel that it should be a feature.

Comment: Additional information. One of my concern is that I will be getting a number back that requires a higher precision than even a double can provide. In that case, I am worried that it will be rounded up as well. For example, if the API returns a value of `6.099999999999999999999999`, I do not want it to be stored as `6.1` but as `6.099999999` with as many `9s` as the precision allows.

Comment: The value it should store for the value 6.1 as 4 byte float is exactly 6.099999904632568359375 or the hex value 40C33333. Or is it stored as text?

Comment: @okysabeni: This is just arithmetic. When you round the value 6.099999, the result is _not_ 6.099990. You round a value of 9 up, not down.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, MySQL stores FLOAT and DOUBLE in IEEE754 format, not text.

Comment: @BillKarwin: If it is in IEEE754 format, then a float with text value 6.1 gets the actual value I mentioned, exactly 6.099999904632568359375, and the text value 6.099999904632568 is stored as the same value, i.e. as hex 40C33333. Tested with my own `exact` program, but also verifiable on several websites. So the value 6.1 is a rounded output value (probably a roundtrip value).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Could be, but in my test above, `FLOAT` rounds the value but `DOUBLE` does not.

Comment: @BillKarwin: probably because the value will not roundtrip when displayed and parsed as `6.1`, as double. `6.099999904632568` becomes `6.099999904632568359375` too, when parsed as double, while `6.1` becomes `6.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375`, i.e. not the same value. The output `6.1`is therefore not a roundtrip value for `6.099999904632568`, in double. But it is a roundtrip output for that value in float. See my answer.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for all the comments. I will add more comments on Rudy's answer above.

Comment: @BillKarwin If I understand you correctly, your recommendation of using double for higher precision is apt for this specific example. However, my worry is that I will get another number that requires a higher precision than what a double can provide. If that is the case and MySQL always rounds it, I should convert the actual decimal to what my data type precision can handle. For example, if the number is `0.099999999999999999999`, I will have to truncate a few of the `9s (i.e. 0.099999)` to fit within my datatype precision. That feels strange to me.

Comment: I would be interested to hear the use case that requires a number with that many digits of scale. In other words, [You Aren't Gonna Need It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: That is fair Bill. I did encounter an issue of precision which leads me to investigate this.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to summarize my findings as an answer.

When I save a value such as `6.099999904632568` into a float data type, MySQL represents it as `6.1`. When I change the data type to `decimal with precision 64 and scale 30`, the `6.099999904632568` automatically appears without me updating the value.

It seems that MySQL did save the original representation of the number but there is no way to return that value as a float. When I switched the data type to decimal, MySQL knows how to represent that correctly and returns it correctly.

This is baffling to me. If MySQL knows the original representation, why can't I fetch the original value back without it being typecasted as a float. Also, since `6.099999904632568` is of a higher precision than what 4 bytes can handle, how does it store the original representation?

More questions that are unrelated to this original question.

Comment: Your findings are not correct. MySQL does not store your float as `6.1`, as `6.1` is not representable by a (binary) floating-point number. What you're seeing is the behavior of the float-to-string conversion routine, as Rudy explained, probably combined with double-to-float rounding on the way to the database.

Comment: So, let's try to understand this statement `probably combined with double-to-float rounding`. My thought was that if it is rounded to float on the way to the DB, then how can it get back the precision after I change the data type to decimal with a higher precision? That was the confusing part for me.